# Cannot call multiple times tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

My code is below.

Code1:

```
  from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter as tk2
    def call_second():
        import tk
        return
  root = Tk()
    E = tk2.Entry(root)
    E.pack(anchor = CENTER)
    B = Button(root, text = "OK", command = call_second)
    B.pack(anchor = S)
    root.mainloop()
```

Code2:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk1
def close_window():
    global entry
    entry = E.get()
    print entry
    root1.destroy()
root1 = Tk()
E = tk1.Entry(root1)
E.pack(anchor = CENTER)
B = Button(root1, text = "OK", command = close_window)
B.pack(anchor = S)
root1.mainloop()
```

When I run code 1, press the ok button, it calls the second code. When I close it and again I press the button on code 1, I can't call the GUI again.

Comment: You can't have two root windows in a Tkinter program. Take a look at the Toplevel widget.

Comment: What's with the double imports?

Comment: Double imports serve no purpose. The problem isn't about the import, it's about multiple root windows. You shouldn't call `Tk()` more than once in a tkinter program.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.